# Aura.loadComponent(): Failed to initialize application

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have developed several lightning components, which can be accessed in salesforce1 by tab. I have an error only in Salesforce1 which mainly show after the code modification, please see the screenshot below:
[image]

My component is the first tab in Salesforce, so when I open Salesforce1, my application is going to load.
Here is my first component shown in application.
ComponentNavigator.cmp

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable" controller="UserSearch">
<ltng:require styles="/resource/SLDS0121/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-ltng.css" />
<aura:attribute name="home" type="Boolean" default="true"/>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
<aura:handler event="c:ChangeView" action="{!c.changeViewAction}"/>
<aura:registerEvent name="GetUserInfo" type="c:GetUserInfo"/>

<style>
     div.pullToRefresh + div {
     height: 100%;
     }

     .viewport {
     height: 100%;
     }

     .scroller.actionBarPlugin {
     padding-bottom: 0px !important;
     height: 100%;
     }
</style>

<div aura:id="container" class="slds container" style="height: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
    <aura:renderIf isTrue="{!(!v.home)}"><c:SellerHeader /></aura:renderIf>
    <div class="slds-scrollable--y" id='senoble-content'>
        {!v.body}
        <div style="height:4rem"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<aura:if isTrue="false"><c:SearchClient /></aura:if>
<aura:if isTrue="false"><c:UnknownClient /></aura:if>
<aura:if isTrue="false"><c:ConsultationQueue /></aura:if>
<aura:if isTrue="false"><c:ProductCatalog /></aura:if>
<aura:if isTrue="false"><c:ClientAccountDetail /></aura:if>
<aura:if isTrue="false"><c:GroupProduct /></aura:if> 
<aura:if isTrue="false"><c:ListProduct /></aura:if>
<aura:if isTrue="false"><c:ProductDetail /></aura:if>
<aura:if isTrue="false"><c:OrderHistory /></aura:if>
<aura:if isTrue="false"><c:OrderCmp /></aura:if>
```

In ComponentNavigatorController.js, In the doInit function, I added an alert for testing, the popup show before the first line code of doInit function, so I suppose the controller is not been called before showing the error popup.

```
({
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    alert('init componentNavigatorController');
    helper.goTo(component, 'AdvisorHomeComponent', event);
},
changeViewAction : function(component, event, helper) {
    var componentName = event.getParam("componentName");   
    helper.goTo(component, componentName, event);
},
```

})

In componentNavigatorHelper.js I initialize the component by add AdvisorHomeComponent.cmp dynamically :

```
try{
        $A.createComponent(
        "c:" + name,
            {UserInfo:userInfoObj},
        function(newComponent){
            //var content = component.find("content");
            //content.set("v.body", newComponent);
            if (component.isValid()) {
                var body = component.get('v.body');
                if (body.length > 0) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < body.length; i++) {
                        if (!$A.util.isEmpty(body[i]))
                            body[i].destroy();
                    }
                    body.length = 0;
                }
                body.push(newComponent);
                component.set("v.body", body);
            }

        }
    )
    } catch(e) {
        //console.log("Error : " + e);
    }
```

Here is AdvisorHomeComponent.cmp

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable" controller="UserSearch" access="global">
<ltng:require styles="/resource/SLDS0121/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-ltng.css" />
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
<aura:registerEvent name="ChangeView" type="c:ChangeView"/>
<aura:attribute name="UserInfo" type="Object" />
<aura:handler event="c:RemoveCurrentClient" action="{!c.removeClient}"/>
<aura:registerEvent name="GetUserInfo" type="c:GetUserInfo"/>

<div class="slds slds-text-align--center slds-text-heading--medium" >
    <div class="slds-text-align--center slds-container--center slds-max-small-buttons--stretch" >
        <img style="width:50%" class="logo-image" src="{!$Resource.images + '/images/logo1.png'}"/><br></br>
        <div class="slds-text-align--center slds-container--center slds-max-small-buttons--stretch" style="width:50%;">
            <ui:button label="{!$Label.c.Home_Page_01}" press="{!c.searchClient}" class="slds-text-heading--medium menu-button slds-button slds-button--neutral slds-not-selected" />
            <ui:button label="{!$Label.c.Home_Page_02}" press="{!c.unknownClient}" class="slds-text-heading--medium menu-button slds-button slds-button--neutral slds-not-selected" />
            <ui:button label="{!$Label.c.Home_Page_03}" press="{!c.consultationQueue}" class="slds-text-heading--medium menu-button slds-button slds-button--neutral slds-not-selected" />
            <ui:button label="{!$Label.c.Home_Page_04}" press="{!c.productCatalog}" class="slds-text-heading--medium menu-button slds-button slds-button--neutral slds-not-selected" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-hide" aura:id="chooseShopPopup">
        <div aria-hidden="false" role="dialog" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
            <div class="slds-modal__container">
                <div class="slds-modal__header">
                    <h2 class="slds-text-heading--small">{!$Label.c.Choose_Shop_01}</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-modal__content">
                    <div>
                        <ui:inputSelect class="slds-select" aura:id="myShop" multiple="false" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-grid slds-grid--align-spread button-container">
                        <div>
                            <ui:button aura:id="save_shop_btn" press="{!c.selectShop}" class="slds-col--padded slds-button slds-button--brand">{!$Label.c.New_Custo_11}</ui:button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop--open"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Anyone can help to remove the pupup?

UPDATE : This error popup is show only in Winter17, I have deployed my lightning component to a summer16 environent, I don't have this error popup.

UPDATE : The error popup is only show in Salesforce1 in ipad. If I run https://namespace.my.salesforce.com/one/one.app in Google Chrome, I don't have the error message.

Comment: It'd be better if you paste your relevant code section.

Comment: Hi, @tugce,  thanks for your advice.  Code added here,

Comment: You have to debug your init handler with console.log statements. Looking at the error message, seems like somewhere some parameter is passed wrong.

Comment: @SantanuHalder ,  I added an alert in the first line in doInit function in ComponentNavigatorController.js, the popup show before the first line code of doInit function, so I suppose the controller is not been called before showing the error popup.